# SVN Export Command not Working

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am Using Cygwin, I want to Do SVN export I am using Following Command.

```
svn export http://SVNpath D:\Test -r 10 --username svntest --password svntest --force --non-interactive
```

It works Fine. But If there is Space in **`D:\Test Folder`**

```
svn: E205000: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: E205000: Error parsing arguments
```

Does I Need to replace Space with **`%20`**.

Please Guide me.

Comment: try using quotes around the path but I'm not surprised that paths with spaces produce problems ... you should avoid them in general, e.g. use dashes/underscores instead

Answer (score 4):

If a path contains spaces you must surround them in Quotes:

```
svn export http://SVNpath "D:\Test Folder" -r 10 --username svntest --password svntest --force --non-interactive
```

If you don't then it thinks **D:\Test** is one argument and **Folder** is another.